# Highest top 15 items from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, highest

I am using Java -7. I want some help cause i stuck, i have a list that i add values all the time but in the end i want get the latest 15. The list handles DonateTable class
that contains .getTime() which return long (System.getCurrentMilliseconds)

and i want to use this value to get the latest top 15. So higher ms = latest value. But idk how. This is my code

```
public ArrayList<DonateTable> getLog(int objectId)
{
    ArrayList<DonateTable> data = new ArrayList<>();

    for (DonateTable dt : list)
        if (dt.getObjectId() == objectId)
            data.add(dt);

    return data;
}

public static class DonateTable
    {
        int _objectId = 0;
        String _service = "";
        long _time, _points = 0;

        public DonateTable(int ObjectId, String service, long time, long points)
        {
            _objectId = ObjectId;
            _service = service;
            _time = time;
            _points = points;
        }

        public int getObjectId()
        {
            return _objectId;
        }

        public String getService()
        {
            return _service;
        }

        public long getTime()
        {
            return _time;
        }

        public long getPoints()
        {
            return _points;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Comparator for `DonateTable` class and use the `getTime()` value to sort instances of it.

```
public class DonateTableByHighestTimeComparator implements Comparator<DonateTable>{

      public int compare(DonateTable o1, DonateTable o2){
         return - Long.compare(o1.getTime(), o2.getTime());
      }
    }
```

You can use this comparator in this way :

```
List<DonateTable> data = new ArrayList<>();
...
Collections.sort(data, new DonateTableByHighestTimeComparator());
```

And at last you can get a sublist view of the first 15 elements of the sorted list :

```
List<DonateTable> top15Elements = data.subList(0,15);
```

Comment: and how to implement it, im confused. Like ur class simply compare the values taken from 2 elements but how it works with all elements and gives top 15?  ps thanks for answer tho

Comment: You provide the comparator and the list to the `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` static method.

Comment: Nop it didn't work in the "game" i make.. I did it this way you show me sir.            https://pastebin.com/Vpp0QbaX

Comment: Indeed. I had used the minus sign in the comparator to reverse the natural order of long comparator as you want to order them by highest (reverse natural order)